# java debugging library

Tags: java, debugging, frameworks

I'm searching for a debugging framework that can be used to implement the UI portion of the debugger - elements like windows, watches, source view, popup menus, etc. Ideally I should be able to just write some glue code between my backend (which provides disassembly, memory access, etc) and this "framework", and end up with a debugger.

I am not looking to debug java code itself - rather want to lift the UI and what not. :)

Any suggestions? I've found jswat, but not sure how easy it will be to integrate with its GUI component, cause its based on netbeans and might require a lot of glue code. I need a fairly basic debugger that can be integrated into my own project - rather than a standalone tool.

Comment: The dbeugger in eclipse, netbeans and IntelliJ are all open source. Could you create a plugin or modify one of these to do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

What about using jdb (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/jdb.html), source code, according to Oracle is available:

> Full source code for jdb is included
>   as part of the example code in the
>   Java 2 SDK's lib/jpda directory

You could hack it so instead of printing to the console, you can get the messages and print them in your UI.

Comment: have you read my question? i am not debugging java, and my VM simulator (backend) is already providing the same facilities as gdb/jdb.

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting your question right, specifically, you can use the Visual Debugger in Java Swing and JavaFX GUI applications on NetBeans for example. by starting your debugging session and go to **Debug> Take GUI Snapshot**.

When you choose Take GUI Snapshot, the IDE will take a snapshot of the GUI and will open it in the main window.

This provides a way for you to locate the code based on the GUI instead of searching through the code.